# Postman Collection Runner: exported results do not have complete responses

Tags: rest, postman, postman-collection-runner

I am using the **Postman** tool and created collection.

I have executed a collection using **Postman Collection Runner**, then I am able to view results. It is fine.

But when I exported the results file the using *"Export Results"* tab, I am not able to see complete requests and responses in the exported file.

How can I get all the requests and responses in the exported file?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by saving all that data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a similar answer to a different question. I don’t think that the export on the collection runner will get you a full list of that data.

[How to export/download Response Body into an external file from Postman Collection Runner Results?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48113414/6028443)

Comment: Thanks Danny ,it's working for me .i am to able to get response also in exported json file.

Comment: Please don't post answers which are effectively just links to other answers (by your or someone else). Post one good answer, then vote/flag to close the other questions as duplicates. If the question is not a duplicate, *tailor your answers to the question.*

Comment: Point taken. Still learning the correct etiquette of the platform.

Comment: Thanks @Makyen for suggesting !

Comment: Not sure if the original question which was duplicated here ever got an accepted answer; for those who are OK with getting response data from collection runner as a string, [here's a quick workaround using environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51049530/3344534)

Comment: Seems like a bit of a mess of JS code but I guess it works :)